# What do you call the product of a matrix's diagonal elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

The trace of $A$, an $N\times N$ matrix, is $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N A_{ii}$.

What do you call $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^N A_{ii}$?

Comment: The product of the diagonal elements? ;-) Unless the matrix is triangular, then it's the determinant.

Comment: For a triangular matrix, that is its determinant :P  I don't know if there is a specific name for this operation.

Comment: I'm writing software to implement this operation (as part of determinant calculation ;), and am wondering what to name this generic operation. If this is only found in the context of determinants and has no other commonly-known names, I won't bother giving it a formal name.

Comment: For a general square matrix, the product is almost always **not** the determinant!

Comment: I would never call this the determinant for that reason. I'm tempted to call it a geometric trace or multiplicative trace though neither is really great.

Comment: You could call it the exponential of the trace of the entrywise logarithm :-)

Comment: Just call it a multiplicative trace and leave a definition of this term somewhere in comments to your code; anyway, this function has too few applications to merit a name.

Comment: @user1551 I thought 95% of mathematics was inventing fancy terms for half-a-reason . Everyone, thanks for your advice. Please note this question is 2.5 years old—I think I wound up not extracting this operation into its own function (as in, code), since it was only used in one place, in calculating the determinant of a matrix after LU decomposition.

Comment: How are there still upvotes for people calling this the determinant?

Comment: People are especially interested in the trace because it is independent of the choice of basis. However, your $\prod_{i=1}^nA_{ii}$ does not enjoy this property, so its not as interesting.